# Understanding the Jmeter log output

Tags: jmeter

I have finished running a sample run on my app using Jmeter. The end of the log file looks something like this:

```
INFO o.a.j.r.Summariser: summary +  24267 in 00:00:18 = 1363.7/s Avg:     0 Min:     0 Max:    11 Err:     0 (0.00%) Active: 0 Started: 1 Finished: 1
INFO o.a.j.r.Summariser: summary = 795647 in 00:10:10 = 1304.1/s Avg:     0 Min:     0 Max:  1003 Err:     0 (0.00%)
```

Why are there 2 summaries? which one do I use?

Answer (score 0):

First line with `summary +` is the latest execution, whereas second line with `summary =` is overall execution summary.

i.e.

If running a load with 100 threads with single http request, first line will say `summary +` with each iteration, and with addition of commulative `summary =` +100
and overall summary after 10 iterations will say `summary =` 1000 samplers.

You should use the first one if monitoring realtime performance.